# CSS span tag in paragraph

Tags: css

I have to go from a) to b) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hWxJ.png
(the green stock-image is from a sprite)

I'm having following HTML-code:

```
    <p class="stock"><span class="img"></span>in stock</p>
```

And following CSS-code:

```
   p span.img {
       display:inline-block;
       width: 14px;
       height: 17px;
       padding-right: 5px;
       background: transparent url(images/page1/tho_main_sprite.png) -0px -580px;
   }

   p.stock {
       font-size: 9px;
       color: #000;
   }
```

I tryed to give some height and line-heigt to p.stock, but no result...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about vertical-align? http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

Comment: Or else, how about `position:relative` on the img.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) could help

```
p span.img {
       display:inline-block;
       width: 14px;
       height: 17px;
       padding-right: 5px;
       background: transparent url(images/page1/tho_main_sprite.png) -0px -580px;

       vertical-align: bottom;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a hacked method of doing it but it achieves what you are looking for.
First put the text "in stock" in a span.

```
<p class="stock"><span class="img"></span><span class="line">in stock</span></p>
```

Make both spans block and float left. Also add line-height

```
p span.img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 14px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: transparent url(images/page1/tho_main_sprite.png) -0px -580px;
}

p.stock span.line {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So some of my margin and width values will be incorrect, don't know the rest of code but you can fix easily.

Let's make two spans in the paragraph:

```
p span.img {
       display:inline-block;
       width: 14px;
       height: 17px;
       background: transparent url(images/page1/tho_main_sprite.png) -0px -580px;
       float: left;
   }

p span.txt {float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 5px;}

   p.stock {
       font-size: 9px;
       color: #000;
       clear: both;
       width: 150px;
   }

<p class="stock"><span class="img"></span><span class="txt">in stock</span></p>
```

PS: Margin explanation, it has four parameters that accepts. Direction goes clockwise

margin: from-top from-left from-bottom from-right

Comment: this would be counter-clockwise? is it clockwise or is it the way you described in your PS?

Comment: true I have mistyped, correction :

margin: from-top from-right from-bottom from-left

Comment: that's what I thought - I was just checking :)